# how to call jsp file from java?

Tags: java, jsp

I have two jsp file and one java file. My constraints is if jspfile1 call java then java file call the jspfile2.  Is it possible?
How to achieve this?

Comment: No offense meant to the existing answers, but if you sketch what you want to do a bit more extensively, possibly with your setup and some code, you would probably get better, well, more useful at least, answers.

Answer (score 3):

If by "Java file" you mean a Servlet, you can use the RequestDispatcher:

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/my.jsp").include(request, response);

 request.getRequestDispatcher("/my.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Comment: This is probably the cleanest way (perhaps the way the J2EE developers *wanted* it to be).

Answer (score 1):

The *normal* way is using a `Servlet`. Just extend `HttpServlet` and map it in `web.xml` with a certain `url-pattern`. Then just have the HTML links or forms in your JSP to point to an URL which matches the servlet's `url-pattern`.

E.g. `page1.jsp`:

```
<form action="servletUrl">
    <input type"submit">
</form>
```

or

```
<a href="servletUrl">click here</a>
```

The `<form>` without `method` attribute (which defaults to `method="get"`) and the `<a>` links will call servlet's `doGet()` method.

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Do your Java code thing here.
        String message = "hello";
        request.setAttribute("message", message); // Will be available in ${message}.

        // And then forward the request to a JSP file.
        request.getRequestDispatcher("page2.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

If you have a `<form method="post">`, you'll have to replace `doGet` by `doPost` method.

Map this servlet in `web.xml` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servletUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so that it's available by `http://example.com/contextname/servletUrl`. The `<form>` and `<a>` URL's have to point either relatively or absolutely to exact that URL to get the servlet invoked.

Now, this servlet example has set some "result" as request attribute with the name "message" and forwards the request to `page2.jsp`. To display the result in `page2.jsp` just do access `${message}`:

```
<p>Servlet result was: ${message}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsp` files get converted to a `servlet`. You cannot call them directly.

**EDIT** : typo fixed.

Comment: but you should not access the auto-generated servlets directly. You should dispatch the request using a URL, and let the container figure out where it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Do a http web request.