# calling jsp or javascript from java

Tags: java, jsp

Is it possible to call a JSP page from Java (I have written below method in Java only not on jsp) ?                      I want to do something like..

```
public void testmethod(){

  if(somecondtion){
    show some messege to the user.
 }  


}
```

Comment: We really need some more info here. Are you handling a request and want to programmatically call a JSP? What is the context here?

Comment: yes I want to call programmatically JSP. I have my method..         public void testmethod(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
if(somecondtion){    
 show some messege to the user.  
}

I tried with response.sendredirect("myjsp"); but control not going to jsp

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call jsp file from java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437768/how-to-call-jsp-file-from-java)

Answer (score 1):

if your java code is in client side you can hit the server using Url class as follows

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.xyz.com/xyz.jsp");//i.e your Url
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
```

better refer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URL.html for better usage of Url class methods

Answer (score 0):

Heard of servlets ?
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437768/how-to-call-jsp-file-from-java) question is infact a duplicate, which you would have got on searching.

Answer (score 0):

You need servlets. Lots of example around the web

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/

http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html

and many more